# I am facing a problem in JavaScript/ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in ReactJS on post API. I have given a task to create some text fields in which I have to give some values and then on click of a submit button the information from text field will be submitted to POST API which I have taken from JasonPlaceHolder.

I have written a code which is given at last. Whenever I click Register button the value in last input field (which in my case is "EMAIL") overrides the values of all the input fields.

A screenshot of my problem is also attached:

[image: Screenshot of Problem]

**Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
          error: null,
          isLoaded: false,
          items: [],
          inter:0,
          ID: '',
          Name: '',
          username : '',
          Email: ''
        };
this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  updateInput(event){
    this.setState({ID : event.target.value})
    this.setState({Name : event.target.value})
    this.setState({username : event.target.value})
    this.setState({Email : event.target.value}) 
    }
  handleSubmit(){
    var dict = { id: this.state.ID, name:this.state.Name , username: this.state.username , email: this.state.Email };

    axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', dict)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      this.setState({isLoaded:true,
                      flag:1,
                    })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      alert(error);
      console.log(error);
    })
    }

  render() {

    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;

    if (this.state.inter == 0){

      return(
      <div>

<form>    
    <p>ID:<input type="text" name="ID" onChange={this.updateInput}/> </p>
    <p>Name:<input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.updateInput} /> </p>
    <p>User Name:<input type="text" name="username" onChange={this.updateInput} /></p>
    <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.updateInput} /></p> 
</form> 


  
      <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
      Register
      </button>

      </div>
      );
 

    }else{

      return(

      <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} >
      Register
      </button>

      <h1> Post Request Submitted Successfully</h1>


      </div>

      );
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updateInput method overrides all the other fields, that's why the last updated field (the email) is the one you are seeing on the request payload.
To solve this you can separate the updateInput method for each input field or inside updateInput check which field you're currently updating and update only that field.

You can check here for more details:

https://medium.com/@zacjones/handle-multiple-inputs-in-react-with-es6-computed-property-name-e3d41861ae46

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the fields like this,

```
updateInput({target: {name, value}}){
    this.setState({[name]: value});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your updateInput logic to this.

```
updateInput(event){
  this.setState({[event.target.name] : event.target.value})
}
```

Comment: i hav tried this but this time output on console show empty spaces instead of input values when register button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the updateInput method. change it to.

```
const { name, value } = event.target;
this.setState(state => ({
  ...state, [name]: value,
}));
```

N:B You will have to make the names of the input element same as the state field.